# What data type is a Range in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use some code like this, and it's failing:

```
data = Range("A1")
MsgBox data.Offset(1,1)
```

This seems like it should print the value of cell B2, but instead it gives me an error (`Run-time error 424: Object required.`).

So what data type does the expression `Range("A1")` return, and how do I declare `data` to be of the correct data type to store it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Range` is an object.
That means you need use `set` to assign an object reference:

```
Dim data As Range
Set data = Range("A1")
```

[Background information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa192490.aspx):

> Set Keyword: In VBA, the Set keyword is necessary to distinguish
>   between assignment of an object and assignment of the default property
>   of the object.

Comment: Would it be fair to say that there are two operators here: `<x> = <y>` which sets the default property of `<x>` to the value `<y>`, and `Set <x> = <y>` which sets `<x>` equal to `<y>`?

Comment: That's fair except that `Set` doesn't set `x` equal to `y` as much as it creates a reference to `y`. I should also mention, to clean-up at the end of your code, you should `Set data = Nothing` to decrement the reference count and allow it to be garbage-collected.

Comment: That's another way of putting it, yes.

Answer (score 2):

The data type for a range is, surprisingly enough, `Range` :-)

If you *ever* get a message that an object is required, then you almost certainly need to use `set`:

```
set data = Range("a1")
```

This is a classic 'gotcha' that most people encounter. The full code snippet would be:

```
Dim data As Range
Set data = Range("a1")
```